# Скрипт на QPython замедляется когда телефон переходит в блокировку

Tags: android, python, qpython

В общем есть смартфон c Android. Есть скрипт на python который запускается в QPython3 в консоле. Когда телефон активен - то есть не в заблокированном режиме - ну я тычу пальцами в него, например, то скрипт работает нормально. А когда телефон лежит и переходит в блокировку, или я его блокирую, то скрипт сильно замедляет свое выполнение. Это выражается так.

Вот есть код который просто пишет в консоль текущее время каждые 10 секунд:

```
import time
while(True):
  t = time.ctime(time.time())
  print(t)
  time.sleep(10)
```

И вот лог консоли:

```
# Тут все идет нормально:
Wed Dec  5 13:16:38 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:16:48 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:16:58 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:17:08 2018

# Тут кскрипт замедляется:
Wed Dec  5 13:18:31 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:21:10 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:28:31 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:28:52 2018

# Тут снова нормально:
Wed Dec  5 13:30:27 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:30:37 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:30:47 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:30:57 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:31:07 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:31:17 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:31:27 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:31:37 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:37:38 2018

# Тут снова медленно:
Wed Dec  5 13:38:38 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:44:40 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:48:39 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:51:36 2018
Wed Dec  5 13:52:44 2018
```

Это как раз периоды, когда либо телефон был активен и скрипт выполнялся нормально, либо когда на блокировке и скрипт тормозит.
Но это не совсем так. В период блокировки тоже бывают моменты когда все выполняется нормально.

В чем тут проблема? Кажется что какой-то режим энергосбережения или типа того усыпляет процессы или что-то типа того? Или тут что-то тривиальное?